# Error: Display data form database to webpage

Tags: php, html

I want to display my database into my webpage in tables. but it cant, i pretty sure that my database name is same. if i run, `".$no."`, `".$row['nama']."`, `".$row['email']."` and `".$row['message']."` will displayed on webpage. not data from database. please help.

here is my code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Nama</th>
     <th>E-mail</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
<?php 
include "conection.php";
$no = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment");
if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$no."</td>
            <td>".$row['nama']."</td>
            <td>".$row['email']."</td>
            <td>".$row['message']."</td>
        </tr>
        ";

    $no++;
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

the error will be like this:
[image]

this is my conection.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "toefl";

$koneksi = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo 'database error : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please write Error message

Comment: Are you sure your php-code is executed?

Comment: just test this code <?php $num = 1; echo $num; ?> it will display 1

Comment: i sure, because if i try that php-code in other program, it will work

Comment: ever heard of [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php)?

Comment: you are mixing mysql with mysqli

Comment: Well it surely looks as if the PHP part is not being processed. Is your file named correctly, that is, does it have a `.php` extension and are you running it on a web server with PHP enabled?

Comment: no, i am a beginner in web

Comment: If you are using the latest version in PHP, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and removed. Verify your error logs for more info.

Comment: i have changed that into .php extension and the error now is: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given on  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM comment"); code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You are mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`. Please don't do that. Check the below code (changes are commented):-*

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Nama</th>
     <th>E-mail</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody><!-- check the change -->
<?php 
include "conection.php";
$no = 1;
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM comment"); // don't mix `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`
if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {// don't mix `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`
        echo "<tr><td>".$no."</td><td>".$row['nama']."</td><td>".$row['email']."</td><td>".$row['message']."</td></tr>";
        $no++;
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

*Note:- this code file extension must be `.php`.*

Answer (score 2):

You forget a i. Change `mysql_query()` to `mysqli_query()` and `mysql_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Chnage conection.php. Change all mysqli methods to mysql

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "toefl";

$koneksi = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

if (!$koneksi) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully'
mysql_select_db($db_name, $koneksi) or die('Could not select database.');;
?>
```